# System Center 2012 Alternatives

Tags: sccm, system-center, system-monitoring, sccm-2012

Are there any good alternatives to System Center 2012?
I'm looking for a system platform that allows gives us a replacement for SCCM, SCOM, EdnPoitn Protection, DPM and Global Service Monitor and can run in the cloud to monitor/manage other servers in the cloud.

We have over 30 Windows 2012 servers that run in the *public cloud* (some in Azure, some in Rackspace and some in a third-party host) that we want to manage, match and monitor.

Our first preference was to use System Center 2012 Data Center Edition however in order to monitor/manage 30 servers in the public cloud we need 4 Licences for System Center 2012 Data Center Edition.
This is the Licencing documentation
http://download.microsoft.com/download/B/4/A/B4A98A4E-2F43-489D-8761-5362C8C2C328/System_Center_2012_R2_Licensing_Datasheet.pdf

And the very last paragraph specifies:

> Q: Can I extend a Server ML to manage applications running on the
>   public cloud?
>
> A: Yes, with the License Mobility through Software Assurance benefit,
>   you can assign Server ML to manage applications running on a public
>   cloud infrastructure. System Center 2012 R2 Standard licenses allow
>   you to manage two virtual OSE in a public cloud, while System Center
>   2012 R2 Datacenter licenses allow you to manage up to **eight virtual
>   OSEs in a public cloud**.

This statement on its own makes System Center 2012 unusable for us.

PS>> I know there is a *duplicate* question [Are there complete System Center Configuration Manager alternatives?](https://serverfault.com/questions/178819/are-there-complete-system-center-configuration-manager-alternatives) but that question is more than 3 years old and it's about System Center 2007.